# How to use EPOCH in JPQL?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, kotlin, jpql

I want to create a query using JPQL.

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in seconds using **EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-d.delivered_at))** in this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*
FROM delivery_specs d
LEFT JOIN payments p ON d.payment_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN packets packets ON packets.delivery_spec = d.id
LEFT JOIN bundles bundles ON packets.bundle_id = bundles.id
WHERE p.state='0' AND d.state = 'DELIVERED' AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-d.delivered_at)) > 2
```

But this query throws a lot of exceptions. When I delete the extract part problem is gone.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT d " +
            "FROM DeliverySpecEntity d " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH PaymentEntity p ON d.payment.id = p.id " +
            "JOIN FETCH d.packets packets " +
            "JOIN FETCH packets.bundle bundle " +
            "WHERE p.state = '0' AND d.state = 'DELIVERED' AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-d.created_at)) > 21600 ", nativeQuery = false)
    fun findDeliveredAndNotPaidDeliverySpecs(): List<DeliverySpec>
```

Comment: Add the exceptions as update to your question.